# System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Neo.Settings' threw an exception

Tags: linux

I'm building the Neo private chain, but there's a mistake I can't solve.

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'Neo.Settings' threw an exception

[image: e]

Comment: Was this solved? Having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem is with your **`config.json`** file. Check out if it is correct or not.